# Normal vector to a plane

Tags: calculus

Find a normal vector to the plane with spherical equation: $$\cot(\phi)=2\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)$$

I don't understand how you would go about finding a normal vector to this type of equation. Help?

Answer (score 3):

$\sf Hint$:

$$\cot \phi=\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \qquad \cos\theta=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\qquad \sin\theta=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.$$

These relations can be verified visually by [looking at the appropriate picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dc/3D_Spherical_2.svg/500px-3D_Spherical_2.svg.png).

Comment: So would the normal vector be: <cos(theta){\sqrt{x2+y2}}, sin(theta){\sqrt{x2+y2}}, cot(theta){\sqrt{x2+y2}}>?

Comment: @Joy No. A normal vector is a constant. I have no idea why you would think that expression is a normal vector or what meaning you think it has. Remember the equation of a plane in three dimensional Euclidean space is given by $n_1x+n_2y+n_3z=p$, where $(n_1,n_2,n_3)$ is a normal vector.

Comment: oh yes, that's right. I'm not sure how to find it still..

Comment: @Joy: Have you written it down on paper? You should have $$\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.$$ Do you see any factor you can get rid of here? What if you move everything to one side after that? Do some stuff, experiment, write things down, move symbols around, exert some effort, think about where you are and where you can go and where you need to go.

Comment: Ok, well you can take the root x2+y2 out of all three expressions... Then move the z to the other side and get 0=2x+y-z and since that is the equation of the plane ax+by+cz and a,b,c is the normal vector then the normal vector is <2,1,-1> in this case

Comment: @Joy Yes, that's right!

Comment: Thanks! That seems too simple. I think the trig functions just scared me